# FindByOrNullAnd method in Spring Data JPA - cruderepository

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Can someone help me to convert below query with Jpa

> select * from TABLE where  (TYPE='Droid2' OR 
>   EQUIPMENT_TYPE is NULL ) and ACTIVE='Y';

I have tried something like this

```
List<Table> findByTypeOrTypeIsNullAndActive(string type, string active);
```

**Above query does not provide correct list. Any help appreciate it.**

I can make it work by writing @Queryin service, but looking for any solution on criteria query

```
@Query(" select new Table(id, type,active from Table r where (r.type is
NULL OR r.type = ?1) and r.active = ?2 ") 
List<Table> findByTypeOrTypeIsNullAndActive(string type, string active);
```

Comment: This is a pretty weird question, because that is exactly the goal of `@Query` to allow you to make proper queries without having to create a method name like the one you're using.

Comment: Okay, then I will delete this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After RnD I realize that ***@Query*** functionality provided to use in such situation.

Use this way

```
@Query(" select new Table(id, type,active from Table r where (r.type is
NULL OR r.type = ?1) and r.active = ?2 ") 
List<Table> findByTypeOrTypeIsNullAndActive(string type, string active);
```